# How to setup correctly Android Studio for test apps in a BLU cell phone?

Tags: android, android-studio

I´m trying to test my apps from android studio on my cell phone (BLU Energy X Plus):

[image]

As you can see, I already enable the debug mode in my phone. When I try to run my application, from android studio I get this error:

[image]

[image]

In addition to enabling debugging mode on my cell phone, I already installed the generic google USB driver:

[image]

My Windows detects the model of the phone correctly too... I can´t understand whats wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Did you click OK?

Answer (score 1):

**FINALLY I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

I just had to delete the entire **build/** folder of the project, and go to **Build** --> **Re-build project** in Android Studio!

Problem fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting "Application Installation Failed" is because you already have the app installed on your phone, but it was signed with a different certificate. So that message says "you already have an app with this package id, but the signature doesn't match"

Just remove the app you already have on your phone, and try from Android studio again.

Comment: I have never been able to install the app on the phone because this error appears. Also, I thought what you say, but the app I do not find it installed on the phone